# Where can I download the Flash Player redistributable installer

Tags: installation, flash, flash-player

The standard process of downloading and installing Adobe Flash involves downloading a small installer, that will itself download the full Flash version adequate to your system, and perform the complete install.

Is there a way to avoid this? I'm upgrading multiple computers in a network and I want to avoid wasting bandwidth by downloading the same installer multiple times, I need a OEM / redistributable installer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe offers a page where you can [download **almost every version of Flash Player**](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html) since version 2, including Flash for Windows, Linux, mac OS and Android.

The installers are quite big (some are about 150 MB), but they include 32 and 64 bit versions, for multiple OSes, (including Windows XP / Vista / 7 / Server 2003 / Server 2008 / Linux Redhat / Linux Ubuntu / Solaris), include debug versions, standalone players, activex, exe, MSI, mac zip / dmg, linux tar.gz and dedicated uninstallers.

Answer (score 7):

The [**Adobe Flash Player Distribution**](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html) page contains links to the latest EXE and MSI standalone installers for Windows (as well as versions for other supported Operating Systems). If you are not interested in the huge all-in-one installers on the other page, get these instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am dumb but with the links provided in the other answers, I could not find a standalone player, just the installation process popped up after opening the provided exe-file.

Only on this Adobe page I found standalone players: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

For instance the [Windows Flash Player 13 Projector (EXE, 9.95MB)](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/13/flashplayer_13_sa.exe)